# Where do I put module elements in Checkstyle config file?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I've a simple problem, when I run maven checkstyle, and then go to check what are the problem, I have that:

`Line is longer than 80 characters (found 98).`

Do someone know how to set it more than 80 characters ? I found few things on the internet, but they don't tell where I need to put that:

`<module name="LineLength">
    <property name="max" value="120"/>
 </module>`

Do someone have a clue ?

Cordially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to put these module configs into a config file such as the following.
**Note:** Where *LineLength* goes depends on the Checkstyle version. Checkstyle 8.24 and higher: directly under *Checker*; Checkstyle < 8.24: under *TreeWalker*.

Example for Checkstyle 8.23 and earlier:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">

    <!-- FileSetChecks go here ("parent = Checker") -->

    <module name="TreeWalker">

        <!-- TreeWalker checks go here ("parent = TreeWalker") -->

        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="max" value="120" />
            <property name="ignorePattern" value="^\s*\*\s*\S+$" />
        </module>

    </module>
</module>
```

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460297/1005481), you can subsequently tell Maven where your config file is, or you can specify it inline (not recommended). In either case, you will need to obtain a copy of the config file you are using now, and modify it.

In plain old Maven Checkstyle 3.0.0, the config file would be [this one](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.18/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml). If you specify a Checkstyle version in your Maven config, modify the version number in the URL to match it.

Comment: FYI from approximately checkstyle 8.24 the `LineLength` module is not allowed as a child of `TreeWalker` and must be a child of `Checker`.

Comment: Ah, ironic, the breaking changes now affect the SO answers, too. You are right, from 8.24 onwards, it goes under Checker directly. Anything earlier as shown. @NickBreen

Answer (score 1):

you can configure a custom checkstyle configuration by configuring the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` (which you obviouisly already use)

you can use [custom-checker-config](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html) or [inline-checker-config](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/inline-checker-config.html)